# What's wrong with this quiz game in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the browser to display a random image (among 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc), which the user should identify and type an answer. The browser should reply with "correct" or "incorrect".

What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT:** Now it works! I updated the code. Thanks for the hints. Happy New Year!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Identify the fruit</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var N = 4;  // number of images
    var fruitname = new Array( 
        "apple",        // name of 0.jpg 
        "orange",       // name of 1.jpg
        "banana",       // name of 2.jpg
        "pineapple",    // name of 3.jpg
     );     
    var samplefruitnumber; 
    function Initialize() {
        samplefruitnumber = Math.floor(N*Math.random()); 
        var DisplayedImage = samplefruitnumber + ".jpg";
        document.getElementById("id_main_image").src=DisplayedImage;
        document.getElementById("replytouser").innerHTML = "...";
        document.getElementById("useranswer").value = "";
    }
    function CheckAnswer() {
        if (document.getElementById("useranswer").value == window.fruitname[window.samplefruitnumber]) {
            document.getElementById("replytouser").innerHTML = "CORRECT!";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("replytouser").innerHTML = "INCORRECT! The correct answer is " + window.fruitname[window.samplefruitnumber];
        }
        document.getElementById("beginbutton").innerHTML = "Sample another";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Identify the fruit</h2>
<p><button type="button" id="beginbutton" onclick="Initialize()">Begin</button></p>
<p><img id="id_main_image" src="default.jpg"></p>   
<p>Enter the name: <input type="text" id="useranswer"><button type="button" onclick="CheckAnswer()">Submit answer</button></p>
<p>Your answer is <span id="replytouser">...</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, you're not waiting for the image to load before executing your code.

Comment: Avoid `prompt` and `alert`. It'll only prove to more pain than it is worth. Using them also removes the opportunity to learn about simple DOM / event model tasks.

Comment: @user2864740 Which commands should I use, then?

Comment: @Sebastian An INPUT for the answer and a SPAN for the result might be appropriate.

Comment: @user2864740 I tried to do as you tell me, but I can't manage to make it work: see the edited question. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: @Sebastian That's a start! JavaScript programming [in browsers] is largely *event based*. So the next task is to add an *event* to the input (or, perhaps better, 'button' next to it). When <enter> is pressed or the button is pressed *then* the code to check the state will be called.

Comment: @user2864740 Like this? The "begin" button works, but the "check answer" button doesn't... :(

Comment: @user2864740 Aha! I managed to make it work! I'll update the question. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value in the array

```
var DisplayedImage = fruitname[samplefruitnumber] + ".jpg";
```

Comment: This part is ok. I forgot to say that I have files 0.jpg, 1.jpg etc in the same folder. (Sorry about the omission, I edited the question.)

Answer (score 0):

One major aspect of JavaScript is to provide interaction between the user and the site, app, etc. It is a safe assumption that your objective falls into this category. The proper way to write such code is to use events. Using prompts and alerts is a terrible way to interact with the user.

If you are making a quiz, use form controls like `<input>`, `<button>`, `<output>`, etc.

Also, you have multiple choice questions then you'll need to know how to collect elements and values into NodeLists and/or arrays.

Most importantly you'll need to know how to use event/listener/handlers and how `e.target` can help you determine the element that is clicked.

**Details are commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// Define counter outside of main block
var idx = 0;

// Register the click event on button#btn...
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  /* This is an array of arrays of strings in 
  || which each sub-array has 4 strings
  */ // Options 4 per quiz question
  var opt = [
    ['&#127827;', '&#127815;', '&#127819;', '&#127822;'],
    ['&#127818;', '&#127805;', '&#127813;', '&#127840;'],
    ['&#129364;', '&#129361;', '&#129365;', '&#129372;']
  ];

  // Array of 3 strings -- one for each question
  var que = ['Which one is a citris?', 'Which one is a vegetable?', 'Which one is a fruit?'];


  /* Template Literal's interpolation of variables
  || made creating this string very easy.
  */
  const QA =
    `<hr>
  <figure id='Q${idx}'>
   <figcaption>${idx+1}\. ${que[idx]}</figcaption>

    <input id='A${idx}0' class='A' name='A${idx}' type='radio'>
    <label for='A${idx}0'>${opt[idx][0]}</label>
    <input id='A${idx}1' class='A' name='A${idx}' type='radio'>
    <label for='A${idx}1'>${opt[idx][1]}</label>
    <input id='A${idx}2' class='A' name='A${idx}' type='radio'>
    <label for='A${idx}2'>${opt[idx][2]}</label>
    <input id='A${idx}3' class='A' name='A${idx}' type='radio'>
    <label for='A${idx}3'>${opt[idx][3]}</label>
    
</figure>`;

  // The TL will be inserted into the DOM
  document.querySelector('.dock').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', QA);

  // Increment the count
  idx++;
});

var sec = document.querySelector('.dock');

sec.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Array answer key
  var ans = ['A02', 'A13', 'A21'];
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt !== e.currentTarget) {
    if (tgt.checked) {
      var x = tgt.id.charAt(1);
      if (tgt.id === ans[x]) {
        console.log('Correct!');
      } else {
        console.log('Wrong!');
      }
      //console.log(tgt.id);
      //console.log(ans[idx]);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.A {
  display: none;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 18px;
}

label {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.A:checked+label {
  border: 3px ridge #0ff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #111;
}

#btn {
  margin-left: 70%;
  width: 64px;
  width: 84px;
  font-size: 24px
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-width: 20%;
  margin-left: 80%
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Identify the fruit</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <h1>Identify the fruit</h1>
    <button id='btn'>Next</button>
  </header>
  <section class='dock'></section>


  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly questions, but where should I put the scripts in order to run your code in my browser? In the <head> of the .html file?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian that is a possibility, but the best *thing* to put it in is either an external file or 2nd best in a `<script>` block. The best place in the page is to place them before the closing body tag at the bottom of the page i.e. before this:`</body>`